# 403 Forbidden on nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, ubuntu-12.04, laravel-5.1

I keep getting `403 Forbidden`

[image]

---

My settings:

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

**default**

```
server {
        listen   80;


        root home/laravel-app/;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name example.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
              root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;

        }

}
```

---

**Update**

I followed this instruction : [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-12-04)

---

Any hints/suggestions on this will be a huge help !

Comment: did you install php5-fpm?

Comment: Can you go through the error logs of nginx and see what error does it say when you receive Status 500? I have a hunch  your `sock` file might have the wrong permissions which is leading to that status 500. It's either that, or something in the configuration of your PHP.

Comment: Well, you can try to do `chmod 666 (or 777) /var/run/php6-fpm.sock`, restart nginx and try again. If that works, you might need to go into `/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf` and check the `user` and `group` as well as `listen.owner` and `listen.group`. You might need to add the user under which `nginx` is running to the same `group` php is running so you don't have issues. Normally the php `sock` is with permission `0660`.

Comment: Did you try: `chown -R www-data:www-data /home/benu/home/forge/ssc-portal`. Or `chmod +x /home/benu/home/forge/ssc-portal/index.php`?

Comment: I'm all set now. My site is loading now. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33481198/4480164) works for me.

Comment: Please check `error.log`

Comment: Have you tried changing your `try_files`? I believe it should end with a `php` extension and not an `html` extension

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to specify an absolute path for your `root` directive. Nginx uses the directory set at compile time using the --prefix switch. By default this is `/usr/local/nginx`.

What this means is that your root, which is currently set to root `home/laravel-app/` causes nginx to look for files at `/usr/local/nginx/home/laravel-app/` which presumably isn't where your files are.

If you set your `root` directive to an absolute path such as `/var/www/laravel-app/public/` nginx will find the files.

Similarly you'll note that I added `/public/` to the path above. This is because Laravel stores it's `index.php` file there. If you were to just point at `/laravel-app/` there's no index file and it'd give you a 403.

Comment: Also, a mistake I've made many times is to forget to run `php artisan key:generate` from the root of my laravel project. If you don't set the `APP_KEY` environment variable, you can get 403 errors even if your nginx config is correct.

Comment: After all edit config file, don't  forget reload file config nginx, this command in terminal:  nginx -s reload

Answer (score 1):

you need to have a rule for php files (in the default file)

```
# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on (...)
#
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

        # With php5-cgi alone:
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php5-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: essentially, you need a php location rule.

Comment: I added your code in my `default` file. I run `sudo nxginx restart`. I still get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The error you added in your update indicates that nginx is attempting a directory index from your ssc-portal folder. Since you appear to be using a basic nginx installation, the only reason a directory index should fail here is if nginx is unable to find the listed index options.

In your server block, you are telling nginx to try the following locations in order when a directory listing is requested (a URI that ends with a trailing slash): index.php, index.html, then index.htm.

If none of those files is found, the directory index request fails.

My best guess is you have your index.php file in the wrong place. Did you move it up from the ssc-portal folder?