# Nginx Error 404 to all laravel project or certain

Tags: nginx

Currently I'm developing laravel project and brew install nginx for web server,
but somehow I get an error 404 for my laravel project when I open it.

So I tail to see what's going on

`tail -f /usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log`

```
    Output : the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1<br>

    *1 directory index of "/Users/user/Projects/new-project/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1
```

Then I try to change the user to user    www-data; as suggested in other solution but still cannot open.

```
    user    www-data;
    worker_processes  1;
    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }
```

```
    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  test.localhost;

        location / {
            root   /Users/user/Projects/test;
            index  index.php;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           /Users/user/Projects/test;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            #fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```

Im using macbook unix terminal catalina

Answer (score 0):

As per Laravel documentation for nginx,

> Your root folder has to point the public directory of your project `/path/to/Project/public`

Follow this guide https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/deployment

Also check out this thread. [403 Forbidden on nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33443918/403-forbidden-on-nginx-1-4-6-ubuntu-laravel)

Comment: to make it weird some project can open some cannot, all using the same format I use like above, and recheck couple times the path as you mentioned, it is the actual path I currently used